# RTCMTLVideoView freezes when rendering large frames on iPhone11

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, webrtc

I create the RTCMTLVideoView the usual way and attach RTCVideoTrack to it. When the video resolution is higher than 1000 (for example 1720x1200) the playback inside rtcVideoView freezes for few seconds occasionally then unfreezes.

I have a web client that renders the same video track with no lags so it's not webrtc or traffic issues as we are in the same network.

Has anyone experienced the same behaviour? Any ideas appreciated. Thanks

```
...
#if arch(arm64)
    var rtcVideoView: RTCMTLVideoView!
#else
    var rtcVideoView: RTCEAGLVideoView!
#endif
...

func showRemoteVideo(videoTrack: RTCVideoTrack) {
    #if arch(arm64)
        rtcVideoView = RTCMTLVideoView(frame: bounds)
        rtcVideoView.delegate = self
    #else
        rtcVideoView = RTCEAGLVideoView(frame: .zero)
    #endif
        
    rtcVideoView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    rtcVideoView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
    addSubview(rtcVideoView)
        
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        rtcVideoView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        rtcVideoView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        rtcVideoView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor),
        rtcVideoView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor)])

    videoTrack.add(rtcVideoView)
}
```

Comment: looks like, It should not be a render issue. Please check if you have some other logic in your code like encoding/decoding frames etc. Also please paste the stats of stream you are getting. And also check the packet loss...

Comment: @Daljeet Thanks. Can you please give me a hint about how to check a packet loss? You mean print some stats of the peerConnection or use wireshark to physically check network packet loss?

Comment: yes, packet loss you should get in stats(peerConnection) or try the webrtc stats(stream) API. Try to get more details.

Comment: Also check the frameRate..